# I accepted "Apple Developer Program License Agreement ", but it is not hide

Tags: licensing, app-store-connect, wwdc

I accepted "Apple Developer Program License Agreement" in the Member Center, but the notification is not hide in the iTunes Connect. I don't have in the Member Center any License Agreement in this moment. What do I do?
It includes following

> Agreements, Tax, and Banking
>   Review the Paid Applications Schedule.
>   The iOS paid applications schedule (“iOS Schedule 2”) and the Mac paid application Agreement schedule (“Mac Schedule 2”) have been combined into a single Schedule 2 covering both programs, and the Custom B2B schedules (“Schedule 3”) for iOS and Mac have been combined as well. To create new paid apps and in-app purchases and upload binaries to the App Store, the user with the Legal role must review and accept the Paid Applications Schedule (Schedule 2 to the Apple Developer Program License Agreement) in the Agreements, Tax, and Banking module.
>
> To accept this agreement, the user with the Team Agent role must have
>   already accepted the Apple Developer Program License Agreement in the
>   Member Center.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Additional to Member Center you need to go to "Agreements, Tax, and Banking" in iTunesconnect and on top you will see a row with your address and some info. Next to it there is a button "Amendments". There is no word of "Schedule 2" or "Schedule 3" whatsoever. You have to click on this "Amandments" and procceed by accepting. After that everything will be fine. For some reason I was not expecting it to be behind this "Amandements" so hope it might help also somebody else. If you don't have "Agreements, Tax, and Banking" in iTunesConnect, you need user with Legal role in order to do that.

Comment: Thank you! I already sent a message to Apple support)

Comment: @Alexsander How did you sent a message to Apple support? Facing same problem. Did they resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes, they helped me. But I followed the answer is above after the notification was hide. @nOObiOS

Comment: I can't find any link for amendments in Agreements, Tax and Banking.

Comment: i found Request rather then Amendments. Clicking on Request and accepting also fixed my issue.

Comment: The Click on the "Request" and than agree the Agreements worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me, it should be click on "Request" to make things clearer